# How to open drop down list after clicking on image in same position?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, toggle

i'm developing one  web site. In that web site i have a page which contains the customer list arranged in row format. Each customer row contains different fields like priorities of MD,CEO and so on. Depending on priority value, i shown the image.

Priority can contain one of the value from following list-
high,medium,low,not assigned

Now i want to give the facility to quick update of priority value. Means if user click on one of priority(MD,CEO) then it should show drop down list which having list as high,medium,low,not assigned. And then user select one of the value & depending on the selection value get updated to particular customer.

Issue is how to give that dropdown and all that?

Comment: @adn_295: not yet. but i want some suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your question may vary upon your needs/design of your web page.As per my understanding, you want one dynamic drop down to be pop up after clicking on the image.
For this, you can set the image as the background of the DIV element.On the onclick event of that DIV, you can create drop down dynamically OR you can display already exciting drop down with the onclick event handler.By capturing selected value from drop down, you may then insert those records in the table row.
Hope this helps.